# .Net core angular app cant locate ngx bootstrap modules

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, ngx-bootstrap

I am using .net core 2.1 angular app. I just fetched my teammates UI code. When I run the app, it throws a Cannot /Get error. In logs it says it cant find some ngx-bootstrap modules.

When I check in Node modules, I see it has all the modules the app cant locate. Can someone please help me dig down what might be the issue.

Here is what the logs are saying:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with couple of changes

Try to reinstall `ngx-bootstarp` with the latest version check that your `package.json` have `ngx-bootstrap` dependency before reinstalling

The problem might be in your `node modules` make sure you have your `node modules` in the .net core project root folder not in the `src` folder or `clientApp` folder - if it exists in those folders map the `node module` to the root folder on `angular.json` file

I think this might solve your problem - happy coding !!